# Installing locally express and stylus

Tags: node.js

I am really new at node js. I was wondering if any one can tell how to install express framework and stylus in a directory which i want. I have installed both globally but cannot find a way to install it locally.A simple suggestion will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> cd myFolder
```

create a README.md

```
> npm init
```

fill in details

```
> npm install express stylus --save
```

You'll then have a express and stylus installed locally and contained in your package.json